# Checking null values in database

Tags: c#, sql

I have a database with stores a sizeable chunk of binary data. A remote app which checks the database in the office.

I basically want the remote app to check that the data exists without having to 'download' it from the remote database.

```sql
SELECT BinaryData FROM DB WHERE BinaryData IS NOT NULL
```

would work, but it would download the data also, I just want a simple check.

Any ideas

Comment: You want `SELECT count(*)`?

Comment: I guess your BinaryData has some sort of `Key`. Why don't you check if that key exists ?

Comment: Which dbms are you using?

Answer (score 1):

You can select the count of Not Null rows. This way you will not have to download the binary data to the remote app.

```sql
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM DB WHERE BinaryData IS NOT NULL
```

Comment: Hi @megabytes. If it helped you please mark it as an answer, so that it will help the community to find the answer fast.

Answer (score 0):

Just don't select any data to be downloaded.

```sql
SELECT NULL FROM DB WHERE BinaryData IS NOT NULL
```

Comment: Better use the `SELECT COUNT(*)` as [Ry- suggests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52532217/checking-null-values-in-database#comment92003749_52532217).

Comment: @UweKeim Why is this a better solution? (Looking for a factual answer and not an opinion)

Comment: Because `SELECT NULL` will return one row per original row. Why do you want those multiple rows? The only useful thing you can do with multiple rows containing no data is a) throw them away (having potentially wasted some server resource to generate (some) of them) or b) count them. If you're planning to do (b), just have the server do it. If you're planning to do (a), ask yourself why.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever Helpful explanation, thanks for that!

Answer (score 0):

another way for Checking not null value

```
SELECT COUNT(*) as Count_BinaryData FROM DB WHERE DATALENGTH(BinaryData) > 0
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using SQL Server (2008+) you can use `EXISTS` which could be faster than simple `COUNT(*)` because it stops selecting rows on first match.

```
IF EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM DB WHERE BinaryData IS NOT NULL)
    SELECT 1
ELSE SELECT 0
```

Alternatively you can write something like this (in this case you will get 1 if there is a match and no rows selected if there isn't)

```
SELECT 1 WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM DB WHERE BinaryData IS NOT NULL)
```

More examples can be found in [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/exists-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017).